# Is there a difference between _NT_SYMBOL_Path and the Visual Studio symbol path?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Is there a difference between the _NT_SYMBOL_Path environment variable and the Visual Studio 2010 symbol path? In this ([Why are my local dlls taking forever to load after setting _NT_SYMBOL_PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3548966)) answer it is claimed that these are two different things.

"In Visual Studio 2010, they've made this explicit by (if it's set) including _NT_SYMBOL_PATH in the Debugging Symbols dialog." ([Why are my local dlls taking forever to load after setting _NT_SYMBOL_PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3548966))

In my Visual Studio 2010 installation I only have the MS Symbol Server entry at the top. When I set the _NT_SYMBOL_Path environment variable the dialog still looks the same and the debugger has the same behavior.

Comment: Did you log out and log back in to ensure the environment variable setting is effective?

Comment: Yes, the symbol loading information in the module window is the same.

Comment: Could you please paste you symbol path value? Does the variable appear in your Tools -> Options -> Debugging Symbols dialog?

Comment: After restarting my machine I have a new entry in the symbol window "Envoironment variable _NT_SYMBOL_PATH". Obviously logging out and logging in doesn't suffice.